# Is it okay to combine Log-in and Sign-up for passwordless/magic-link logins?

Tags: usability, design-patterns, login, registration, signup-signon

The generally received wisdom online seems to be to keep your log-in and sign-up/register flows separate. The reason being, that they are very similar and it is easy for users to get confused.

I plan on using a passwordless system, where users enter an email address and are sent a link to complete their login. The only information I collect about my users though is their email addresses. As such the process for logging in and registering are not just similar, they are exactly the same.

Login:

- You enter your email address
- You get sent a link
- You click the link to log in

Registration

- You enter your email address
- You get sent a link
- You click the link to log in

I was thinking of having a login/register form consisting of an email address field, and a button that simply says "Log in / Register". In either case, you are told an email has been sent to the address entered to login.

#### My Question

- Are there any major UX problems with this approach?
- Do the reasons for separating log-in and sign-up still apply?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I combine login and signup with a single button?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/114335/can-i-combine-login-and-signup-with-a-single-button)

Comment: People are expecting 2 different screens for registration and login.  Even though they do the exact same thing, I'd still give them the 2 different screens.